# How to refer to a state for a javascript function without refering to its name explicitely

Tags: javascript

How can I set state https://jsfiddle.net/7q1530sp/10/ doesn't work

```
function o(){
 this.state = true;
}

o.f = function() {
  alert(this.state);
}
o.state = false;
o();
o.f();
```

instead of refering to o explicitely within its function https://jsfiddle.net/7q1530sp/9/

```
function o(){
 o.state = true;
}

o.f = function() {
  alert(this.state);
}
o.state = false;
o();
o.f();
```

Is there a way to refer to o without using its name ?

Comment: Use a plain variable instead?

Comment: What do you mean ? A global variable ? That wouldn't be clean.

Comment: The ability to do `o.state = false;` from anywhere isn't really any better - maintainability-wise, that's similar to having a global `state` variable

Comment: it is still better for documentation because it is attached to o ;)

Comment: Better to return an object with two properties then, instead of abusing a function like a key-value collection

Comment: It's an existing code I don't want to change so my question : is it possible do progressive change.

Comment: The code is quite strange - I'd really consider refactoring it, if you're to the point of asking a question like this

Comment: It's a contrived example, the real code is much bigger and complex of course.

Comment: `o` is just a variable that "points to" the instance of your function. You don't even need it, you could just add `()` afterwards to call it. `(function(a,b){return a+b})(1,2) //3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, to initialize a function you should use NEW before executing it, example:

```
var my = new fn()
```

However, I would advise you to opt for prototypes:

In addition to being comfortable to use, in case of complex projects, they will also allow you to divide your project into multiple files while keeping the code clean and tidy!

I leave you a small example on how prototypes are used:

```
var my = function(){}
my.prototype.test = true;
my.prototype.run = function(){
    console.log(this.test)
}

var w = new my();
w.run();
w.test = false;
w.run();
```

**Update:**
Of course, you could also globally change the value of the variable like so:

```
var my = function(){}
my.prototype.test = true;
my.prototype.run = function(){
    console.log(this.test)
}

new my().run();
my.prototype.test = false;
new my().run();
```

**Output:**

```
true
false
```

Comment: thanks have to study a while before marking it as right answer :)

Comment: ok!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)